# How do I export my .hs contract to .Plutus?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

How do I export my .hs contract to .Plutus? Please provide step by step guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a good example in [Exercise4-solution](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/main/Alonzo-solutions/exercise4/Exercise4-solution.md) of Alonzo-testnet program.

Source code is here: [plutus-helloworld](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/tree/main/resources/plutus-sources/plutus-helloworld), if you have any doubt check the code to understand what it does.

Basically you need to:

1. Create an executable `plutus-helloworld` as defined in `plutus-helloworld.cabal` file
2. Compile the plutus file using: `cabal run plutus-helloworld -- 1 helloworld2.plutus`
3. Build the address: `cardano-cli address build --payment-script-file helloworld2.plutus --testnet-magic 8 --out-file helloworld2.addr`

Then you can follow the exercise solution.